# Laravel 5.1 - return eloquent model with multiple relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following models Show, Presenter, Image.

Shows can have multiple presenters. Presenters have one image.

I can do this to get a presenter with their image:

```
$presenter = Presenter::with('image)->find(1);
```

And I can do this to get a show with presenters:

```
$show = Show::with('presenters')->find(1);
```

Is there a way I can return a show with presenters and their image in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to eager load nested relationships.

```
$show = Show::with('presenters.image')->find(1);
```

Comment: Does this work for an infinite amount of levels? Assuming all the relationships exists obviously could you do `Show::with('presenters.country.city.image')` for example?

Answer (score -1):

If you defined your relations you can get them all in one query very easy:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations